# prevent re-render using useMemo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-usememo

I am doing a fetch every 30 seconds and saving the response in my redux state. What i want to do is prevent re rendering of the component if the response is same as the previous one. To do this i have tried useMemo hook.

```
const details = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.orders.details);
```

This is the state i'm updating every 30 seconds. (Which is an object)

This is how i implemented useMemo

```
const memorizedDetails = useMemo(() => {
    return details;
  }, [details]);
```

And finally my useEffect

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (memorizedOrderDetails) {
      console.log("content changed");
    }
  }, [memorizedOrderDetails]);
```

But even if the updated detail is same as the previous one, it always logs "content changed" every 30 seconds.

Is the way i'm using the useMemo wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to you to use reselect in order to memoize selectors, so if there is no changes it won't render

Here is the link of reselect : https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect